# Make [trump] a synonym of [donald-trump]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I’ve come across a few questions that’s tagged with [trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trump) and I’ve retagged them with [donald-trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump).

As such, can [trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trump) be made a synonym of [donald-trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/donald-trump)?

(I have suggested this synonym at https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/donald-trump/synonyms, it’ll automatically be created once it gets 4 votes.)